# broken dropdown menu code

Tags: windows, tkinter, python-3.5

I was following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PSm-tq5M-Dc a tutorial for doing a drop-down menu in a gui. In the video the code works but i can't get mine too, I think it may have something to do with different python versions.

```
from tkinter import * 

def doNothing():
    print ("ok ok i won't...")

root = Tk()

menu = Menu(root)
roo.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)
subMenu.add_command(label="New Project..."), comand=doNothing
subMenu.add_command(label="New"), comand=doNothing
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=doNothing)

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Redo", comand=doNothing)

root.mainloop()
```

This is the error

```
C:\Users\TheSheep\Desktop\pygui>python dropdown.py
  File "dropdown.py", line 14
    subMenu.add_command(label="New Project..."), comand=doNothing
    ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Comment: you have `)` in wrong place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have few "typos"

- it has to be `root` instead `roo` in `roo.config()`
- `)` has to be at the end of line in both

  ```
  subMenu.add_command(label="New Project..."), comand=doNothing #
  subMenu.add_command(label="New"), comand=doNothing
  ```
- it has to be `command=` instead of `comand=` (see: `mm`)

.

```
from tkinter import * 

def doNothing():
    print ("ok ok i won't...")

root = Tk()

menu = Menu(root)
root.config(menu=menu)

subMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=subMenu)

subMenu.add_command(label="New Project...", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_command(label="New", command=doNothing)
subMenu.add_separator()
subMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=doNothing)

editMenu = Menu(menu)
menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=editMenu)
editMenu.add_command(label="Redo", command=doNothing)

root.mainloop()
```